# Nerve damage in middle finger fretting hand?

Tags: guitar, technique

I have been playing guitar for 20 years and up until a month ago played regularly every day. A month ago I noticed that I was getting an intermittent burning sensation in the underside of my left middle finger, especially when turning my hands over or playing guitar. That has gone now but been replaced with an electric shock feel in the finger tip when I fret or touch something hard, like grabbing an iPad.

It’s a similar vibe to the feeling you get when you knock your funny bone but condensed into the end of the middle finger. I had also been on statins for three months which I stopped in case this is/was a side effect. I’ve been tested for diabetes and it’s negative. This is really scaring me as a) my job is web design so keyboards/mice are a necessity and b) the thought of this not going is just too depressing to think of. I’ve got a follow up docs appointment tomoz but was wondering if anyone had any experience of this. Hope you’re all safe and well. Dave.

Comment: This really needs to be addressed by a doctor, so it's good you have follow-up scheduled. We can't give medical advice here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't offer medical advice here.

Comment: We wish you the best, but this question's beyond our scope. But hey, you might get some other people's stories if you ask in [chat]!